# Ошибка "Fatal error: Uncaught --> Smarty Compiler: Syntax error in template"

Tags: php, php7.4, livestreet

Поставил шаблон, вышли вот такие ошибки:

```html
Fatal error: Uncaught --> Smarty Compiler: Syntax error in template "file:/home/r/acc/site/public_html/templates/skin/themee/header_top.tpl" on line 69 "
" missing closing tag '{/php}' <-- thrown in /home/r/acc/site/public_html/engine/lib/external/Smarty/libs/sysplugins/smarty_internal_templatecompilerbase.php on line 69
```

Стоит PHP 7.4
Строка, на которую ругается:

```html
<div style="background-color: {php}printf( "#%06X\n", mt_rand( 0, 0xFFFFFF ));{/php}; opacity: 0.5;" alt="avatar" class="avatar"></div>
```

Comment: кавычки замените на ординарные у printf

Comment: Спасибо большое!